# Google Maps REST API to Create Custom Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a database table with a listing of thousands of locations.  I would like to create a custom map (accessible from the main Google Maps splash page by going to *Menu->Your places->Maps*.  These are the same maps that you can create yourself at [google.com/maps](http://google.com/maps)) using REST URLs to drop dots associated with my location addresses.  The populated custom map will then be accessed through [google.com/maps](http://google.com/maps).  I am not looking to embed Google Maps on a web page.

I've looked [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/), but I have not been able to find a set of REST URLs that I can use to do this.  Most of the APIs provided by Google comes in the form of client-side JavaScript libraries.

Is there a way to create a custom map using exposed REST endpoints from Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brief answer is no.

Maps Data API has not been available since 2011 (see [Maps Data API deprecation announcement](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ru/2010/11/maps-data-api-deprecation-announcement.html)) and as for now there still is no way of doing it programmatically (see [Allow programmatic access to MyMaps](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2953))